# Accessing different HTML files from javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript file that is being called by 2 html files, I need the javascript to edit the canvas that is on 1.html and 2.html, this doesn't work unless I put both canvasses in the same html file. Is there a way to work around this problem, here is the code:

HTML1

```
        <body>
    <canvas class="canvas" id="canvas1"></canvas>
        </body
    </html>
```

HTML2

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        </head>

        <body>
    <canvas class="canvas" id="canvas2"></canvas>
        </body
    </html>
```

Javascript:

```
    for (var i = 1; i<3; i++) {         
var c=document.getElementById("canvas"+[i]);        
var ctx=c.getContext("2d"); 
ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
}
```

This doesn't work unless I put both canvasses in the same html file, then it works

EDIT: Please note that I do want the code to be running in the background at all times, updating the htlm files I'm not in. The filling and clearing is just a placeholder for my code, which is not part of the problem

Comment: `canvas1` doesn't exist in HTML2 and `canvas2` doesn't exist in HTML1. You need to check before using the canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No there isn't.

Long answer:

JavaScript is always scoped to the current document, so you can't access 2 at the same time. However, there are ways to do this if both documents are in some kind of hierarchy.

If you open a new window from 1.html you can save a reference to that new window and access it's content. [JavaScriptKit: Accessing objects of window via another](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/window4.shtml)

This also works vice versa via the `window.opener` reference.

New in HTML5 is also `window.postMessage`. You might want to look into this as it might serve your need.
[Mozilla Developer Network:window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage)

If you plainly want the same script to work on 2 pages, simply use the same id for both canvasses and not a loop and you should be fine.

```
var c=document.getElementById("canvas");        
var ctx=c.getContext("2d"); 
ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
```

And your html:

```
<!--1.html-->
…
<canvas class="canvas" id="canvas"></canvas>
…

<!--2.html-->
…
<canvas class="canvas" id="canvas"></canvas>
…
```

Answer (score 0):

If you `getElementById` for an element that doesn't exist, you will get `undefined`.

If you try to access a property of `undefined`, you will get an error and the script will stop executing.

After getting the element, test to see if you got an element, and skip to the next loop iteration if you did not.

```
if (typeof ctx === "undefined") { continue; }
```